# Incompatibilities between Mustache.java and Mustache.js template handling?

Tags: java, javascript, mustache, templating

I would like to use [mustache templates](http://mustache.github.io/) in both Java and JavaScript.  I have actually used [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) extensively and love it.  But I have not used [Mustache.java](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java) yet.

Are there any known conflicts or incompatibilities between them?  Meaning -- how realistic is it to expect I could use the same templates in both languages without problems?  Or at least, can folks write templates without having to worry about special things needing to be done depending on the language used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both conform to the [mustache specifications](https://github.com/mustache/spec), passing related tests.

Therefore there shouldn't be any noticeable differences between them (excluding performance).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example -

In Mustache.js -

```
{{#persons.length}}
<h2>Persons:</h2>
<ul>
  {{#persons}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/persons}}
</ul>
{{/persons.length}}
```

In Mustache.java -

```
{{^persons.isEmpty}}
<h2>Persons:</h2>
<ul>
  {{#persons}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/persons}}
</ul>
{{/persons.isEmpty}}
```